# How do I multiply more the one variable by a number simultaneously

Tags: python, list, variables

I have three variables, I would like to know how to multiply all of these variables by another variable `number` simultaneously.

For example

```
number = 2

var1 = 0
var2 = 1
var3 = 2
```

The output should be:

```
0
2
4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just use a simple for loop as follows:

```
number = 2

var1 = 0
var2 = 1
var3 = 2

for output in (var1, var2, var3):
    print output * number
```

This would display:

```
0
2
4
```

Answer (score 8):

Use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

```
>>> number = 2
>>> 
>>> var1 = 0
>>> var2 = 1
>>> var3 = 2
>>> 
>>> [i*number for i in (var1,var2,var3)]
[0, 2, 4]
```

And to print it

```
>>> for i in output:
...     print(i)
... 
0
2
4
```

You can use `map` and `lambda` also

```
>>> for i in map(lambda x:x*number,(var1,var2,var3)):
...     print(i)
... 
0
2
4
```